# What is the meaning of the SAT/SIG/TTF GPS status info?

Tags: gps

When you turn on GPS and some app subscribes for GPS notifications, GPS status info shows up with "SAT", "SIG" and "TTF" info (the last one I know, Time To Fix) but what is the meaning of the first two and what is the meaning of the numbers/symbols (like infinity) shown up next to them?

**Update:** example of the Android GPS status:

```
SAT 0/2 | SIG 19/∞ | TTF 27s
```

The last one means "it took 27s (so far) to acquire GPS signal". I don't know about the first two ones and all those numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Android developers defines the standard parameters 
  [GPS Status](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GPS) to be used by apps.
- Apps can obviously provide more than the minimum information, as in the case of [GPS Status & Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2), whose [help page](https://mobiwia.com/gpsstatus/) 
  and Android documentation put together help decipher.

  - `SAT 0/2`  Number of satellites: GPS in use [+ GLONASS in use] / Total visible. So your phone could detect 2 Satellites but none were used to get a fix (indoors or yet to acquire fix?). This likely corresponds to `getMaxSatellites` in the documentation.
  - `SIG 19/∞` Average signal to noise ratio (0-40dB). This corresponds to `getsnr`
    in the documentation. The second value is the [**D**ilution **o**f **P**recision value](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_of_precision_(navigation)) 
    . You were surely indoors  or fix just started, so without fix the error of the position is `∞`. Linked wiki says readings having value  >20 should be discarded.
  - `TTF 27s` is `getTimeToFirstFix` meaning the time required to receive the first fix since the most recent restart of the GPS engine.